# Is there a Windows equivalent of Android app :"Whatsapp who visited me"?

Tags: 8.1, whatsapp

Is there a Windows equivalent of  Android app :"Whatsapp who visited me"? or any other way out to run this android app on my windows 8. phone?

Comment: There maybe an app which does that.. but there is no way to run the Android app on WP unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no app with this feature for Windows Phone at the moment, and there's also no way of running Android apps on Windows Phone.

Just to avoid any confusion: this is a joke app and does not really work anyway.

> Disclaimer:
>   WhatsApp Spy (Spy) has no relationship with WhatsApp Inc,. Important Note: This application does not work... It's only good for joking with friends: P